# Call wordpress function through functions.php when pressing menu

Tags: functions, menus

I have created a menu through wordpress admin menu creation but I'd like to call wp_cache_flush() when I press every menu item... is there any hook I can call through functions.php so I can execute wp_cache_flush()? Thanks in advance! Cheers! :-)

Comment: Why when clicking a menu item? Why not just when each page loads? Also, _why_? Is there a problem you’re trying to solve? Are you even using object caching? If not this won’t actually clear anything.

Comment: Since for example I added in my plugin js code a `console.log('blahblahblah...');` and once reloaded page with CTRL+F5 that console.log wasn't showed in console so I thought there's something dirty in browser's cache... then I checked first in my wp-config.php to be sure WP_CACHE was not present but the issue was still present, so I was thinking about `wp_cache_flush()` and I thought to call it every time I load each page.... you said when each page loads...you mean like calling it like in header.php?...

Comment: `wp_cache_flush()` has nothing to do with the browser cache. It wouldn't help you.